# parameters of Task in TaskScehduler Arduino

Tags: arduino, esp8266, arduino-ide, arduino-esp8266

What are the different parameters used in the Task class of TaskScheduler Arduino Library?

```
   #include <TaskScheduler.h>
   Scheduler runner;
   Task t2(3000, TASK_FOREVER, &t2Callback, &runner, true)
```

What are the different callbacks that be used in Task Scheduler?

ThankYou

Comment: I am creating a mesh network using esp8266 where 2 of them function as a client and one as a server. on server side code I am using painlessmesh library. This library uses TaskScheduler to schedule the task. So, I want to get the values of clients in one task and want to send those values to the cloud using other Task. 
I want to create a timeout between these task.

Answer (score 1):

The API of the library is well documented in the [wiki on GitHub](https://github.com/arkhipenko/TaskScheduler/wiki/API-Task#creation-1). The corresponding section is the following:

> ```cpp
> Task(unsigned long aInterval, long aIterations, void (*aCallback)(), Scheduler* aScheduler, bool aEnable, bool (*aOnEnable)(), void (*aOnDisable)(), bool aSelfdestruct);
> // OR
> Task(unsigned long aInterval, long aIterations, TaskCallback aCallback, Scheduler* aScheduler, bool aEnable, TaskOnEnable aOnEnable, TaskOnDisable aOnDisable, bool aSelfdestruct);
> ```
>
> Constructor with parameters.
> Creates a task that is scheduled to run every <`aInterval`> milliseconds, <`aIterations`> times, executing <`aCallback`> method on every pass.
>
> 1. `aInterval` is in `milliseconds` (or `microseconds`) (`default = 0 or TASK_IMMEDIATE`)
> 2. `aIteration` in number of times, `-1 or TASK_FOREVER` for indefinite execution (`default = 0`)
>    **Note:** Tasks remember the number of iteration set initially, and could be restarted. After the iterations are done, the internal iteration counter is `0`. If you need to perform a different set of iterations, you need to set the number of iterations explicitly.
>    **Note:** Tasks which performed all their iterations will be disabled during next scheduling run.
> 3. `aCallback` is a pointer to a void callback method without parameters (`default = NULL`)
> 4. `aScheduler` – optional reference to existing scheduler. If supplied (not `NULL`) this task will be appended to the task chain of the current scheduler). (`default = NULL`)
> 5. `aEnable` – optional. Value of true will create task enabled. (`default = false`)
> 6. `aOnEnable` is a pointer to a bool callback method without parameters, invoked when task is `enabled`. If `OnEnable` method returns `true`, task is `enabled`. If `OnEnable` method return `false`, task remains `disabled` (`default = NULL`)
> 7. `aOnDisable` is a pointer to a void callback method without parameters, invoked when task is `disabled` (`default = NULL`)
>
> All tasks are created disabled by default (unless `aEnable = true`). You have to explicitly `enable` the task for execution.